# Unattended wget security implications

Tags: bash, cron, wget

I've written a simple script utilizing wget to collect specific filetypes (.png) from a website. While this works pretty well I'm somewhat concerned about possible security risks.

As it stands wget will just download everything with the .png extension, theoretically it would be possible for the website to contain malicious or trash files that have been renamed.

Is there a way to do some filtering before wget downloads? The files I'm looking to download always share some charcteristics that could be used to identify them (PNG image data, 200 x 300, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced; Size between 80-120kB)
Can --spider be used to atleast sort out the files by size before downloading anything? If so I'd appriciate any help with that!

This could probably be done after downloading using file plus some other commands, but I'd like to avoid grabbing bad data in the first place - any way to do this? Or alternatives that can do something like that?

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PNG files have an 8 byte header which contains the following:

1. 137 A byte with its most significant bit set (``8-bit character'')
2. 80  P
3. 78  N
4. 71  G
5. 13  Carriage-return (CR) character, a.k.a. CTRL-M or ^M
6. 10  Line-feed (LF) character, a.k.a. CTRL-J or ^J
7. 26  CTRL-Z or ^Z
8. 10  Line-feed (LF) character, a.k.a. CTRL-J or ^J

So if you feed the first 8 bytes into `od` you should see something like this:

```
$ head -c 8 knox.png | od -c
0000000  211   P   N   G  \r  \n 032  \n
```

I think that gives you the basis of a pretty good test.

I don't think there is any way to limit wget to partially download a file, but you can do it in curl e.g.:

```
curl -s -r 0-8 "http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad8rgb.png" | od -c
0000000  211   P   N   G  \r  \n 032  \n  \0
0000011
```